# Why can't we call the constructor of the base class within the function body of the constructor of a subclass?

Tags: c#

Why  can't we call the constructor of the base class within the function body of the constructor of a subclass? For example,

```
public class Baseclass
{
  public int X;
  public Baseclass () { }
  public Baseclass (int x) { this.X = x; }
}
```

why

```
public class Subclass : Baseclass
{
  public Subclass (int x) : base (x) { }
}
```

instead of

```
public class Subclass : Baseclass
{
  public Subclass (int x) : { base(x);  }
}
```

or

```
public class Subclass : Baseclass
{
  public Subclass (int x) : { base.Baseclass(x);  }
}
```

My question is more from the perspective of the design of C#, or other similar OO languages such as C++ and Java, which all follow the same design.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Java does not actually allow what you're proposing - while in Java the call to `super()` is inside the subclass constructor's body it is a compile error if there are any statements before that call:

```
// This is Java
public class Subclass extends ParentClass {

    public Subclass() {
        String x = "foo";
        super(); // <-- compile error
    }
}
```

Anyway, the reason is because the runtime (and language specification) demands that the state of a superclass be fully-defined prior to any subclass instance code being executed.

A simple thought-experiment will demonstrate why:

```
// This is C#
public class ParentClass {

    protected readonly Int32 x;

    public ParentClass() {
        this.x = 123;
    }
}

public class Subclass : ParentClass {

    // Using your proposed idea:
    public Subclass() {

        Int32 localX = base.x; // get the current value of `ParentClass.x`

        base(); // call base constructor
    }
}
```

In the example above, what is the value of `localX`?

The answer is "undefined" - and C# and the CLR (and Java) are designed to prevent undefined behaviour - whereas C++ is more forgiving, but that doesn't mean you should do it.

By requiring that all base classes are fully initialized before subclasses prevents an entire series of bugs relating to uninitialized data.

I will say one thing, however - there is no formal reason why we should not be able to execute *static* code prior to calling the parent constructor. We can actually do this in C# but we have to refactor code so it's a static function call via the parent class' constructor parameters, which isn't pretty - nor does it allow data to be passed directly back to the subclass constructor. So I wish we could do something like this:

```
public class ParentClass {

    public ParentClass(String x, Int32 y) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Subclass : ParentClass {

    private static ComplexObject GetComplexObject() {
        // ...
    }

    public Subclass() {
        // All code before `base()` is executed in a static context:
        ComplexObject cmplx = GetComplexObject();
        base( cmplx.X, cmplx.Y );
    }
}
```

Instead we currently need to do this:

```
public Subclass()
    : base( GetComplexObject().X, GetComplexObject().Y ) {
}
```

Or use a static factory method with a private constructor:

```
private Subclass(String x, Int32 y) : base( x, y ) {

}

public static Subclass Create() {

    ComplexObject cmplx = GetComplexObject();
    return new Subclass( cmplx.X, cmplx.Y );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Subclass : Baseclass
{
  public Subclass (int x) : base (x) { }
}
```

Yes this one is the correct answer. I've tried java but the syntax of almost c# codes are different. As soon as you call the base class with constructor on your subclass you need to follow the way you code it from the base class;

You may also try this upon instantiating

```
 Baseclass base = new Baseclass(32);
```